# I have completed this code in hackerrank for second largest no. in javascript but test cases are showing wrong. below is the code

Tags: javascript, arrays

javscript second largest no. code 
please help me solve this program

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
    // Complete the function
    nums.sort();
    //console.log("sorted array", nums);
    let largest_no = nums[nums.length-1];
    let final_array = nums.filter(x => x != largest_no);
    let second_largest_no = final_array[final_array.length-1]
    console.log("filtered array", final_array);
    return second_largest_no;
}
getSecondLargest([2, 2, 1, 2, 5,  1, 5, 3, 4, 6, 6 , 6 , 5 , 5]);
```

Comment: Is there a more specific definition of 'second largest'? I guess they mean count one of the sixes as the largest, but since there is more than one six the answer is still six.

Comment: second largest no. in the whole list all numbers that are same... count as one like 6

Answer (score 0):

If they are looking for "5" as a 2nd largest number by ignoring the duplicates. Then below code can be used to find 2nd largest value.

"Default_Min" can be set as per your requirements.
This algorithm will have O(n) time complexity. which is be better than using sorting and filtering.

```
function SencondLargest(nums)
{
    let max_1;
    let max_2;
    let Default_Min = 0;

    if (nums.length < 2) 
    { 
        console.log(" Invalid Input "); 
        return; 
    }
    max_1 = max_2 = Default_Min;
    for(let i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] > max_1) 
        { 
              max_2 = max_1; 
              max_1 = nums[i]; 
        } 
        else if (nums[i] > max_2 && nums[i] != max_1) 
                max_2 = nums[i];
    }

    if (max_2 == Default_Min) 
        console.log("There is no second largest"+ " element\n"); 
    else
        console.log("The second largest element"+ " is "+ max_2); 
}

var x = [2, 2, 1, 2, 5,  1, 5, 3, 4, 6, 6 , 6 , 5 , 5];
SencondLargest(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `reduce` method to have `O(N)` complexity. So we can [use `reduce` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate through array and have values such as `largeValue: 0, largerValue: 0, largestValue: 0` as accumulator of `reduce` method:

```
const obj = arr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
   a[c] = a[c] || {c};
   if (i === 0) {
      a.largeValue = c;
      a.largerValue = c;
      a.largestValue = c;
   }
   else {
      if (c > a.largeValue && c < a.largerValue && c > a.largestValue) {
         a.largeValue = c;
      }
      else if (c > a.largeValue && c > a.largerValue) {
         if (a.largerValue == a.largestValue) {
            a.largerValue = c;
         }
         else {
            a.largestValue = c;
         }
      }
   }
   return a;
},{ largeValue: 0, largerValue: 0, largestValue: 0 });
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [2, 2, 1, 2, 5,  1, 5, 3, 4, 6, 6 , 6 , 5 , 5];

const obj = arr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
   a[c] = a[c] || {c};
   if (i === 0) {
      a.largeValue = c;
      a.largerValue = c;
      a.largestValue = c;
   }
   else {
      if (c > a.largeValue && c < a.largerValue && c > a.largestValue) {
         a.largeValue = c;
      }
      else if (c > a.largeValue && c > a.largerValue) {
         if (a.largerValue == a.largestValue) {
            a.largerValue = c;
         }
         else {
            a.largestValue = c;
         }
      }
   }
   return a;
},{ largeValue: 0, largerValue: 0, largestValue: 0 });

console.log(obj.largerValue);
```